# Angular Service doesn't return value

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

Im using angularjs in MVC.

Here My Controller.js:

```
//Get User By ID
$scope.GetUserById = function (UID) {
     var Get = UserService.GetUserById(UID);
     Get.then(function (response) {
           $scope.User = response.data;
           alert($scope.User.Address);
     });
};
```

services.js:

```
    //Get By ID
    this.GetUserById = function (UID) {
          debugger;
          return $http.get("../api/UsersData/GetUserById?UID=" + UID);
    };
```

When I'm using the debugger, the alert message is displayed. If I'm not debugging then it doesn't return a value.

What is the issue in my code?

How to display the value to html page?

Comment: Try adding a 'return $scope.User;' or 'return response.data;' after the alert.

Comment: try implementing  'error function' of the returning promise too.

Comment: did u try to use callback function

Comment: want to display user details based on the id

Comment: return $scope.User :  its not working

Comment: Both the times alert is popping or not?

Comment: are you getting data in response.data variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You should get it working with few adjustments.

**Service.js:**

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('MyService', MyService);

//Avoid Minification Problems
MyService.$inject = [ '$http' ];

function MyService( $http ){

    function GetUserById(UID){
      return $http.get('../api/UsersData/GetUserById?UID=' + UID)
                      .then( function (response) {
          if(response){
            return response;
          }
      });
    }

    //Expose Method to External Calls
    return {
             GetUserById : GetUserById
    }

}
```

**Controller.js:**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = [ '$scope', 'MyService' ];

function MyController( $scope, MyService ){

  $scope.GetUserById = function(UID){
    MyService.GetUserById(UID).then( function(response){
     $scope.User = response.data;
     alert($scope.User.Address);
    });
  }

}
```

Make sure what `response` is actually returning with a `$log` or using `console.log` in order to properly alert the address. Do this check also in the service, for instance you should check if `response.address` exists.

You can also use a **Service** instead of a **Factory**.